# Google Maps V3 API: How can I get report of the use of the DIRECTIONS and GEOCODE APIS

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps API v3 in a Web.

And also I am using:

`new google.maps.Geocoder();` (GEOCODING)

`new google.maps.DirectionsService();` (DIRECTIONS for trace routes between 2 places)

Then I went to API Developers Console and create a KEY and I call the Google service in this way usin the key:

http://maps.google.es/maps/api/js?key='the-key-from-api-console'&sensor=true

The intent of this is to keep track of the use of apis to watch that I do not pass the limits of use.

In the API console Google reports me ok about the use of the javascript API v3 counting the number of visits, the number of loads of the maps even the URL of the pages that use the maps.
I can see that my use of this service does not exceed 25,000 requests / day

But i need reports of the use of GEOCODING and DIRECTIONS too and Google is not reporting me this info. In developers console I activated the Directions API,  the Geocoding API and Google Maps JavaScript API v3. But I only get reports of Maps JavaScript API v3.

Report of  Directions API  and  the Geocoding API stay always at 0%. It is as if Google is not using this report.

Could it be that the service should be contracted to have this data or to be other types of APIS enable the console in order to have use of this report?

I've been trying to find information clarifying this for me but I found nothing that completely solved my doubt.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use both services via the methods of the Javascript-API the limits apply to the user that visits the page with the map, the quota of your account is not affected(so there is nothing to count/report for your account/project)

It applies to your account only when you request the [webservices](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/)(usually via serverside scripts).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. 
I will accept this answer as logical considering what Google reports on usage statistics. 

But if that is so, then Google does not control the use of such service in this cass? 
If someone uses it on a website with lots of visitors, for example:Could not mean a lot of additional traffic for Google?

Comment: Of course it's additional traffic. I wouldn't say that google doesn't have control over the usage(I'm sure that they have control and when there is a huge number of requests they will take a  look at the site to see if there is any kind of abuse going on). But as long as the usage doesn't have an effect to any quota there is no need to provide an report.